# Nodejs scraping radio button values - not picking up correctly - stuck - help appreciated

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, radio-button

In a node js cheerio web scraping and traversing application that I am writing, there is a requirement to capture the values of the below variable

`var OrderStruct = obj.RadioValue.value;`

In the html code within a table the values are appearing as

```
<td class='border_main_table_content0' width="20">
<input type="radio" name="Select" value="ven_dm|PROD13SEP2008|200821000006717|B|L|30.0|75|0|0.0|DAY|PROD13SEP2008|PROD13SEP2008|open|0|1285425000|--|1|NRML|NA|0.0|0.0" style='background-color:[Ljava.lang.String;@130e292' onClick="Apply(this.value,this.form,200821000006717,'open','B','NRML','NA','NFO','NA','LIMIT' );checkBO('NRML')">
</td>
```

My code is picking up the OrderStruct variable as

ven_dm|PROD13SEP2008|200821000006717|B|L|30.0|75|0|0.0|DAY|PROD13SEP2008|PROD13SEP2008|open|0|1285425000|--|1|NRML|NA|0.0|0.0

However, when passed on to the next page it is being shown as incorrect value.  Is there anything I am doing wrong here?

Added

In the webpage the variable OrderStruct is getting encrypted using

```
OrderStruct = Base64.encode(AESEncryptCtr(OrderStruct, key,"256"));
OrderStruct =   escape(OrderStruct);
```

and then a new page is called by appending the encrypted value to the url like

```
newwindow=window.open("ModifyOrder.jsp?"+OrderStruct,"ModifyOrder","height=650,width=420,resizable='no',scrollbars='no',menubar='no',toolbar='no'");
```

When i use the same command in node js to navigate to the new page, the url link does not work. Since the encryption logic uses a current time stamp for encryption, I am unable to decrypt the actual cipher to know what value was used. However, I used Fiddler to check the actual url getting generated through the front end and that is not matching with what my code is generating - and hence my concern as to whether the variable OrderStruct was getting picked up correctly.

Hope I am able to explain my problem properly.

Comment: How are you passing the variable to the next page?

Comment: @Take-Some-Bytes have added more details at the end in my original question . Hope that helps.

Comment: @Take-Some-Bytes Am closing this question.  The error was on my end --- was using a wrong key for encryption and hence the result was wrong.  the radio value button getting picked up was correct.  Sorry for the trouble